# How to bind command from ViewModel to a DataTemplate which is in in't own file

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, datatemplate

I am using bindable stack layout with ItemTemplateSelector. My DataTemplates are in another file which is ResourceDictionary included in MainView as MergedResourceDictionay. In one of my DataTempplates I have Label with TapGestureRecognizer that is supposed to trigger command in MainViewViewModel, and that I can't seem to get working....

I tried having `Source={x:Reference MainPage}` in my Command binding, but can't reference it since it's not in same file

> (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: 'Position 28:51. Can not find
> the object referenced by MainPage')

```
<--! this is snippet from MainPage  -->
 <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1">
            <local:BindableStackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Day.TodayEntry}"
                     x:Name="BindableStack" Spacing="10" Margin="10" 
                           BindableLayout.ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CardDetailTemplateSelector}"/>
        </ScrollView>

<--! this is problematic snippet from data template  -->

<Label Text="REMOVE" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="3,0,0,0">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding RemoveEntryCommand, Source={x:Reference MainPage}}" 
                              CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

Comment: You could add your RemoveEntryCommand in the items itself, which would directly bind with your datatemplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that does not work is that XAML compilation look-ups are page-specific which means if you have two different pages and you search using names it will not work in most cases.

What I usually do in such scenarios is I use the parent keyword for my BindingContext!

So assuming your Label (which is in the ViewCell) has a parent which is a Grid you can do something like

```
Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference parentLayoutGrid}, Path=Parent.Parent.BindingContext.RemoveEntryCommand}"
```

Where the number of parents properties required depends on your ViewHeirarchy and which View would have the correct context.

Good luck.

Feel free to get back in case of queries